# Write negative decimal in binary(octal etc..) by hand

Tags: binary, decimal-expansion

How do I convert a negative decimal number into other systems(binary, octal)?

I got the decimal numbers: -22,5 , -60 and 166.

I have to convert them to binary(16 bit) and octal(by hand). I know the system for decimal numbers that are not negative and without decimal point.

Comment: Yes, in germany we use a comma instead a decimal point, sorry!

Comment: Are we allowed to use a positive/negative sign (in which case it's trivial), or are you assuming representation in [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)?

Answer (score 0):

Martin, I believe that you need to use a floating point convention to represent the decimal number.  You can refer to the article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point which shows a number of formats.  I don't understand the significance of representing the value in octal verses binary because the base you choose to represent the value is independent from the data structure dictated by the particular format you choose to represent the numeric value.  I know you must translate this response to German so I hope the idea I offer is clear.  Cheers.